# Symfony2 - Problemas com PreUpdate do Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony-2, doctrine-2, sql-update

Minha entidade `Budget` tem alguns métodos que são executados no `PrePersist` e `PreUpdate`. São eles:

```
/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    if ($this->getStartsAt() !== null) {
        $date = new \DateTime($this->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
        return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
    }
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateTotalBudgetPrice()
{
    $totalBudgetPrice = 0;

    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $totalBudgetPrice += $item->getPrice();
    }

    return $totalBudgetPrice;
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateInstallmentRatePrice()
{
    return $this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice() / $this->getInstallmentRate();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onPreEvents()
{
    $this->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
    $this->setInstallmentRatePrice($this->calculateInstallmentRatePrice());
    $this->setTotalBudgetPrice($this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice());
}
```

O método `generateNextPaymentDate()` é normalmente executado e usa o valor do campo `starts_at`, um campo tipo `DateTime`, da entidade `Budget`. Inserindo um novo ou atualizando um existente, o método funciona normalmente, tendo o seu valor retornado inserido/atualizado no banco.

Já os métodos `calculateInstallmentRatePrice()` e `calculateTotalBudgetPrice()` usam o valor do campo `meters`, um campo tipo inteiro, da entidade `Product`, que é uma *collection form* embutida no formulário `Budget`. Os métodos funcionam, mas é necessário que eu tenha alterado algum campo do formulário principal, qualquer outro valor, para que estes métodos tenham os seus valores persistidos no banco. Caso contrário, são normalmente executados porém não são atualizados.

Eu não sei como arrumar isto. Devo ter esquecido de algo?

Comment: Você está querendo dizer que na primeira vez que a entidade é salva os valores não são calculados; mas nas vezes seguintes, sim?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Não exatamente. Independente de ser a primeira edição ou a décima de um mesmo orçamento, se eu quiser modificar a quantidade de `meters` de um material que aquele orçamento tem, atualmente eu preciso também alterar algum outro campo do formulário de orçamento, seja a data inicial, ou número de parcelas, qualquer coisa para que modifique no banco de dados os valores retornados daqueles dois métodos.